# PHP setting path for export excel

Tags: php, export-to-excel, filepath

i would like to export excel to specific folder where user can save it wherever they want. currently i already succeed with export to excel but i test it locally and it downloaded to my local server folder. i hope someone can help me. thank you.

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$excel=new ExcelWriter("./excel/company".$id.".xls");
if($excel==false)   
echo $excel->error;
$myArr=array("NO", "COMPANY", "ADDRESS1", "ADDRESS2", "ADDRESS3", "POSTCODE", "CITY", "STATE", "PHONE NO", "FAX NO", "EMAIL", "WEBSITE");
$excel->writeLine($myArr);
$qry=mysql_query(" SELECT organizations.*, states.state, cities.city FROM organizations, states, cities WHERE idOrg='$id' AND organizations.state_id=states.idState AND organizations.city_id=cities.idCity");
if($qry!=false)
{
    $i=1;
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $myArr=array($i,$res['companyName'], $res['add1'], $res['add2'], $res['add3'], $res['postcode'], $res['city'],$res['state'], $res['phoneNo'], $res['faxNo'], $res['email'], $res['website']);
        $excel->writeLine($myArr);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question title suggests that you are under the assumption that, using PHP, you can save an Excel file on the client's PC. Not exactly. You can save it to your local webserver (as you've already found out). But to transfer that to the client PC, you should offer it up as a download.

Once the file is done being written (as you are already doing), present the user with a link to the file on your server. They will then be able to choose where it should be downloaded on their PC.

Another possibility would be to write out the excel file data as the HTTP response and set the `Content-Type` header to something like `application/vnd.ms-excel` (or whatever is correct for your file type) and a `Content-Disposition` of `attachment` ([example](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html)).

I'm not familiar with ExcelWriter, so I don't know if it has some kind of a `dump` function or not. Perhaps after you write out the file you just do something like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=company'. $id .'.xls');

echo file_get_contents('./excel/company'. $id .'.xls');
```

Comment: thank you, @Travesty3! sorry for my late reply.i'm so tired last night and fell asleep. :) i've tried as you suggested but the file automatically downloaded to PC, means it did not offer where it should be downloaded. but since it not downloaded to local server folder but to my default downloads folder in my PC, you have helped me a lot. thanks again & happy new year! ;)

Comment: @mella: The option of automatically downloading to the Downloads folder or prompting the user to choose a download location is completely out of your hands. That is handled by the user's browser, so it depends on which browser they use and what settings they've chosen. There's nothing you can do about that. If that is not acceptable for your scenario, the only thing I could think that you could do would be to give the user a link and instruct them to use Right-Click->Save As...

Comment: thanks for your advice, @Travesty3. i have tried it on a web free hosting and it worked and exported the data that i need. but when i try it on my company web hosting where i do my internship, it downloaded the file but there is no data exported inside. any ideas? because of database password protection?

Comment: @mella: Try adding an `else` to your `if ($qry!=false)` statement. In it, do `die(mysql_error());` in order to see if your query is producing an error (like 'unable to connect' or something). This is for debugging, and should be removed before pushing to production to avoid outputting database information to the user. On a side note, you should avoid using `mysql_*` functions. [They are officially deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) (note the red box). Instead, you should use PDO or mysqli, as suggested in the link.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is in their documentation

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.intro.php

excerpt from the above site

```
// sending HTTP headers
$workbook->send('test.xls');
```

> What that means is that we are sending
> our spreadsheet to a browser. But what if we just want to save the
> spreadsheet in our machine? Well, you just have to omit that line and
> give a valid file path to the workbook constructor.
>
> For example, if we wanted to save the same spreadsheet we created in
> our first example to a file named 'test.xls', we would do it like so:

you could then point the user to a link to that file so that he can save it where he likes

Answer (score 0):

```
"./excel/company".$id.".xls"
```

Is a relative path are you sure this is where you want to save it? You can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get the doc root and use that + the path like this.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/excel/company".$id.".xls
```

also don't forget to close the file as well.

```
$excel->close();
```